# Writing SQL statement UPDATE query FMDB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fmdb

I am having trouble `UPDATING` my database using `FMDB`. Here's my `SQL`

```
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Person SET gender= '%@' WHERE name= '%@'",gender,name]];
```

I wonder if i made a mistake by using the `=` sign to compare (If so how could i correct it). Or any other solution. Help?

EDIT :

```
DB Error 7: out of memory
2012-03-30 16:10:03.341 den[5168:f803] Error calling sqlite3_step (1: SQL logic error or missing database) SQLITE_ERROR
2012-03-30 16:10:03.343 den[5168:f803] DB Query: COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: see this may be help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/392536/1126111

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably use this format:

```
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE Person SET gender = ? WHERE name = ?",gender,name];
```

You're also using a commit without starting a transaction, so take that bit out as well.

Comment: Even if i add a string to  `?`, for example gender = 'male' it doesn't get updated in the database. Why is this ? see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941967/updating-sqlite-query-fmdb-beginner#comment12704052_9941967

Answer (score 3):

I used this:

```
FMDatabase * database = [self openDB:[DELEGATE getDatabasePath]];
NSString *query = @"";
query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Person SET gender= '%@' WHERE name LIKES '%@'",gender,name];
[database executeUpdate:query];
[database commit];
[database close];
```

Comment: I also get a Error/Warning called `Out of memory`. May be there's no problem with the SQL and some other problem. Do you know what that error means ? HELP

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:[NSString 
  stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Person SET gender=? WHERE name LIKES ?",gender,name]];
```

In fmdb method [executeUpdate] use "?"  instead of "%@"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Person SET gender= '%@' WHERE name LIKES '%@'",gender,name]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
NSString *updateQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE_NAME SET row_value = %@",@"fmdb"];
Bool updateSuccess = [FMDataBaseObject ExecuteUpdate:updateQuery];
```