# Updating SQLITE query FMDB - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fmdb

I could read from my SQLITE DB, but unable to update it. I wonder if the database is writable.

When i copy the SQL to the SQL console the code gets executed successfully. So there's no problem with the SQL.

```
-(BOOL) updateScores{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"uniques.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
    BOOL success;

    if ([db open]) {

        if ([db hadError]) {
            NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
        } 

        success = [db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Score SET answer='11' WHERE name LIKE 'jack'"]];

        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"OK");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"FAIL");
        }

        [db close];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Problem with DB");
    }

    return success; 
}
```

Comment: what does it print in console ? OK - FAIL - Problem with DB ?

Comment: It says OK, but when i type a select * SQL in the console, it has not got updated.

Comment: Why using *stringWithFormat* if you don't really put any variables inside? Try the literal, if it does not work remove the single quotes.

Comment: Still it doesn't work. Actually I get the status as `OK` meaning the query executed successfully. But when i cross check in the sqlite terminal, it hasn't got updated. Help

Comment: 1: Try to start the application in the Simulator and examine if the uniques.sqlite file has been created on your file system (output `writableDBPath`). I doubt that.
2: Never ever execute a query with `stringWithFormat`. Rather use the solution offered by FMDB. https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb
3: Could it be, that you are trying to update an empty sqlite3 database? Where do you execute your DDL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always pass the arguments to SQL query as an object type, please look at the way arguments are passed to the SQL query. Even if you are passing a number, pass it as

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:someValue]
```

Try this:

```
-(BOOL) updateScores
{
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
  NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"uniques.sqlite"];

  FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
  BOOL success = NO;

  if ([db open] != YES) {
        NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
        return NO; //VERY IMPORTANT
    } 

  [db beginTransaction];
    success = [db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE scores SET answer = ? WHERE name like ?", @"1", @"jack"]; 

    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"OK");
        [db commit];
        [db close];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"FAIL");
    }

   return success; 
}
```