# How to replace specific Row in FMDB?

Tags: ios, sql, fmdb

I am trying to replace specific row in FMDB where my uniq id matches ...

but what is exact syntax for REPLACE Query? i tried to search but i didn't find any
Please Help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use UPDATE query instead of REPLACE.

For mode details about Update query use below url:

[Writing SQL statement UPDATE query FMDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940889/writing-sql-statement-update-query-fmdb)

OR

I have created a project over FMDB in Swift which you can use to solve your issue. FMDB Wrapper class you can use in Objective C project as well.

https://github.com/LalitKY/Swift-FMDB

Hope this helps.